# Dispose unmanaged resources created in Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unmanaged

When an object is created in the .Designer.vb file **from the Windows Form Designer, is a Dispose() call generated automatically for each object or must this be done manually?**

Specifically, I have an object that uses unmanaged resources (by calling ShowDialog(), requiring a call to Dispose()) that is created in the Windows Form Designer. Do I still need to call Dispose() on that object?

Note: It is advised not to call Dispose() more than once on the same object.

Comment: Pretty vague.  Winforms automatically disposes components and controls that were dropped on the form at design-time.

Answer (score 1):

While I dont know the answer, let me tell you how you can get the answer and learn a neat trick for designing components for winforms (might work for others but haven't tried).

Assuming you have a project that already references your component, create a new project and set the "Start External Program" to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" (change this based on your version of visual studio, this is from 2005)

Run this project, which will then run another instance of VS. You have now opened VS in debug mode. Now open your project you are using to build/test your component (from the second instance of VS), set a break-point and test it.  You should be able to see it hit your break-point in the dispose code.

This is great for testing VS Add-ins and designer components.

Answer (score 0):

This was one of those questions where the answer is "because that is the way it works", but then you realize you don't actually know how it is implemented.  So I spent a few moments to dig up the details.

Anything that is a `Control` (button, textbox, whatever) that is added to the `Controls` collection is disposed for you automatically.  This implementation is inherited all the way back from the `Control` class itself.

Anything that is a non-graphical Component (like a Timer for example) that is added to the auto-generated `components` object in the MyForm.Designer.vb file is also disposed for you.  In this case, `components` object, while implementing the `System.ComponentModel.IContainer` interface, will be an instance of `System.ComponentModel.Container` that handles the actual Dispose.

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: I used a tool called Reflector to decompile the code and see exactly where Dispose was getting dealt with.